# Суммировать список. Не получается. Python

Tags: python

```
def calc_stat(listened):  # от англ. calculate statistics, посчитать статистику 
    listenedstatistics = 0
    for i in listened:
        listenedstatistics += (listened[i])
    return f'Вы прослушали {listenedstatistic} песен'# напишите код функции calc_stat
        
print(calc_stat([193, 148, 210, 144, 174, 159, 163, 189, 230, 204]))
```

Comment: Что конкретно не получается? Чтобы было нормальное форматирование кода, вставьте код в вопрос как есть, до первой строки и после последней строки вставьте ```

Comment: Во-первых у вас ```return``` вне функции. Во вторых эту строку ```listenedstatistics += (listened[i])``` желательно переделать вот в эту ```listenedstatistics += listened[i]```

Comment: Лучше скажите, чем этот вопрос отличается от указанного дубликата :)

Comment: Блин ребят простите, не знаю как тут код правильно править. Делете короче. Разобрался.

Answer (score 3):

Вы пишете `for i in listened`  - i - это уже не номер элемента, а сам элемент.

Должно быть `listenedstatistics += i`
А вообще можно сделать проще, встроенной функцией `sum`  :

```
f'Вы прослушали {sum(listened)} песен'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def calc_stat (listened):
    listenedstatistics = 0
    for i in listened:
        listenedstatistics += int(i)
    return f'Вы прослушали {listenedstatistics} песен'
print(calc_stat([193, 148, 210, 144, 174, 159, 163, 189, 230, 204]))
```

**and the end )**